# Order ggplot stacked barchart by specific value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating this ggplot chart

```
# library
library(ggplot2)

# create a dataset
specie <- c(rep("sorgho" , 3) , rep("poacee" , 3) , rep("banana" , 3) , rep("triticum" , 3) )
condition <- rep(c("normal" , "stress" , "Nitrogen") , 4)
value <- abs(rnorm(12 , 0 , 15))
data <- data.frame(specie,condition,value)

# Stacked + percent
ggplot(data, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=specie)) + 
    geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity")
```

How can I make it so that the barchart is order by "nitrogen" in ascending order? Meaning that values from left to right will reflect the increase of the value "nitrogen".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following

```
# Order factor levels by increasing "Nitrogen" values.
lvls <- with(
    subset(data, condition == "Nitrogen"),
    specie[order(value, decreasing = TRUE)])
data <- transform(data, specie = factor(specie, levels = lvls))

# Stacked + percent
ggplot(data, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=specie)) +
    geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity")
```

[image]